# @CreateTimestamp, @UpdateTimestamp. Почему при обновлении записи в create null?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Кто может подсказать, как можно реализовать?
У меня есть поля:

```
@CreateTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Timestamp create;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false)
private Timestamp update;
```

При сохранении в БД новой записи, все хорошо. JSON возвращается с заполненными полями create и update.
А вот при редактировании, JSON приходит с заполненным update, а create null. В БД все хорошо заносится. 
Можно ли сделать, чтобы при редактировании create был не null?

Comment: updatable = false - уберите это

Comment: Тогда в БД будет null после обновления сущности